# quickActionAPI on Lightning App Home Page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, quickaction, lightning-home-page

so for my current project I am trying to remediate a client's business process from classic, which basically pops open a modal with some fields prefilled to create a new object record. I obviously want to use a global (quick) action(right?) but am having trouble referencing it on the global level. A previous developer involved with this client implemented the exact thing I want to do, but on Opportunity, so getting it to launch was easy and made sense, I just can't do it on a global level. Here's the code.

.cmp

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >

<lightning:quickActionAPI aura:id="quickActionAPI" />    

<aura:attribute name="actionName" type="String" />

<lightning:button label="NA SFDC Issue" onclick="{!c.action}"/>
```

.js

```
({
selectAction : function( component, event, helper) {
    var actionAPI = component.find("quickActionAPI");
    var quickAction = "Global.<quickactionAPIName>";
    var args = {actionName: quickAction};
    actionAPI.selectAction(args).then(function(result) {
        var fields = result.targetableFields;
        console.log(fields);            
    }).catch(function(e){
        if(e.errors){
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
},
```

})

One difference is the old code that is working on the object level, is using a design element, where I do not want or need one here, I just want that one process remediated in LEX. Any ideas? Please and thanks!